# Parallel test setup/teardown once per test suite? Test organization

Tags: java, selenium, junit, selenium-grid, saucelabs

I'm new to automated testing/Java, so please forgive me if this is a silly question.

My team is considering using Sauce Labs instead of a local Grid configuration for testing our web-based applications.  I was successful at getting tests to run in parallel based on this code on Sauce's website, https://docs.saucelabs.com/tutorials/java/#running-tests-in-parallel, but I don't like the redundancy of having to specify on each test case what browsers you want to test on.  In addition, the example code only works for desktop configurations and doesn't work for mobile devices (declares OS, version, and browser only).

I modified the code so it now reads name/value pairs from a text file within the Maven project and iterates through each line and sets each name/value as a capability.  With this approach, I don't have to update each of my tests as new browser versions/devices are supported by WebDriver.

In researching how I might change my code to simplify my test suites, I came across the JUnit documentation that suggests this approach is creating dependencies, http://junit.org/faq.html#organize_3.

I'd be interested in people's thoughts on this approach. From a maintenance standpoint, specifying your browsers within your test case seems like a nightmare.  Does anyone have a code example of how they are setting up their test suites or resources that would lead me in the right direction?

I appreciate any input!

Code Example:

```
@RunWith(ConcurrentParameterized.class)
public class NewTest implements SauceOnDemandSessionIdProvider {

    private String capabilities, sessionId, jobID;
    private WebDriver driver;

    public SauceOnDemandAuthentication authentication = new SauceOnDemandAuthentication(CommonConstants.SAUCE_USERNAME, CommonConstants.SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY);

    public NewTest(String capabilities){
        this.capabilities = capabilities;
    }

    @ConcurrentParameterized.Parameters
    public static LinkedList<String[]> browsersStrings() throws IOException {
        LinkedList<String[]> capabilities = new LinkedList<String[]>();

        //get file of desired capabilities.
        File file = new File(CommonConstants.CAPABILITIES_TEXT_FILENAME);

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        //iterate through each line of the file and assign that line to an array
        String line;
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            capabilities.add(new String[] {line});
        }

        //close the file reader
        bufferedReader.close();

        //return the array to each parallel test to be used in the setup() function
        return capabilities;

    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        DesiredCapabilities capability = new DesiredCapabilities();

        String[] caps = capabilities.split(";");
        int numberOfCapabilities = caps.length;
        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfCapabilities; i++) {

            String[] nameValues = caps[i].split(",");
            String n = nameValues[0].toString();

            String v = nameValues[1].toString();

            capability.setCapability(n, v);
        }
        //use this to use Sauce Labs
        this.driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://" + authentication.getUsername() + ":" + authentication.getAccessKey() + "@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub"), capability);

        //use this to use local configuration. Other portions of test case will also have to be commented out...
        /*this.driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capability);*/ 
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {

        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");

        jobID = ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getSessionId().toString();

        updateSauceStatus(jobID);

    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {

        //TODO validate the driver is still active
        driver.quit();

    }

    @Override
    public String getSessionId() {
        return sessionId;
    }

    public void updateSauceStatus (String jobID) {

        SauceREST client = new SauceREST(authentication.getUsername(), authentication.getAccessKey());
        Map<String, Object> updates = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        //TODO
        /*updates.put("name", "this job has a name");*/
        updates.put("passed", true);
        //TODO
        /*updates.put("build", "1.0.2");*/
        client.updateJobInfo(jobID, updates);
        client.getJobInfo(jobID);

   }


}
```

As indicated by the comments, there is still work to be done on this...

Answer (score 0):

My organization runs around 25K tests on average every day on different browsers. We use testNG instead of Junit for test execution. That shouldn't make much difference.

As you rightly pointed out, maintaining the browser at test level is a nightmare. To overcome this, we group the test cases based on functionality and run the whole group. TestNG provides a method to group the tests.

We specify the group name and the browser name in a property file. This property file will be read by the framework and it spawns the correct driver for test.

To run the same tests against different browsers, we create different test builds in CI tool (Jenkins). Each will have its browser property set differently.